# IIS 7.5 set redirect error page but return http 500.22 error

Tags: asp.net, http, web-config, iis-7.5, http-status-code-500

Have two sites on IIS 7.5 server
Each site has the same error page, one operating and one inoperative.
Both have similar web.config structures and there are no significant differences in server settings.Both pipelines are equally integrated with the same integration.
i was googling and do something like ↓, but it was useless.
How can we solve it?
The code below shows the same settings for the web.config files on both sites.

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules>
  <add type="te.test, Version=1.1.1.0" name="testModule" />
</modules>
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error_page/error_test.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error_page/error_test.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
</system.webServer>

<system.web>
<customErrors defaultRedirect="http://test.test/error_page/error_test.html" mode="On">
</customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: i have two sites, Each site has same IIS settings, web.config structure, and set redirect same error page setting but one is activate the other one is not..

Comment: you need to add details like how are you trying to redirect to error pages. The code you have written here doesn't show any redirection

Comment: thanks for your opinion so I modified the contents and added several codes.

Comment: You need to use `<customerrors>` tag as well. Then your website will redirect to the correct error page every time.

Comment: The <customErrors> tag is at the bottom of my code.

Comment: this tag has to be present in system.web.

Comment: sorry I forgot to write that part. The code is inside <system.web>.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was virtual directory(/error_page)
i was configure virtual directory as 'application'